# Rails error include jquery.ui.all

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an error when I try to include jquery.ui.all. All worked perfectly befor that I reboot my computer but now I have this error :

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
```

I rebooted my server, I try to clear the cache from the Rails console and on my navigators and I still have the problem. I also tried to to delete the Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` and still the same error.

Here my both application.js and application.css :

```
//= require ./plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require fullcalendar
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require ./plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min
//= require ./plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min 
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore-min
//= require gmaps_google

 *= require_self
 *
 *  CSS Global Compulsory
 *= require ./plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min
 *= require style
 *
 *  CSS Implementing Plugins
 *= require ./plugins/line-icons/line-icons
 *= require ./plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min
 *= require ./plugins/flexslider/flexslider     
 *= require ./plugins/bxslider/jquery.bxslider
 *= require ./plugins/layer_slider/css/layerslider
 *= require ./plugins/hover-effect/css/custom-hover-effects
 *= require ./plugins/sky-forms/version-2.0.1/css/custom-sky-forms
 *
 *  CSS Theme
 *= require ./themes/orange.css
 *
 *  CSS Customization
 *= require custom
 *= require fullcalendar
 *= require jquery.ui.all
*/
```

And my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use mysql2 as the database for Active Record
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.15"
# gem "mysql2", "0.3.11"

# Use PostgreSql at the database for Active Record
gem "pg"

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Bundle Pagination
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

# Authentification, Authorize, Roling
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify', :git => "git://github.com/EppO/rolify.git"

# Géolocalisation
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'

# API Builder
gem 'rabl'

# Json Parser
gem 'oj'

# Upload de Fichier
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1"

# Fullcalendar
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I find the problem,

The problem is from the update of the gem jquery-ui-rails. Befor the include was :

```
jquery.ui.all
```

and now :

```
jquery-ui
```

Hope that it can me helpful